# Pageswitch with startActivity (Buttonclick)

Tags: java, android, eclipse, start-activity

I tried to realize a simple switch between different activities with buttons. After debugging I got this messages. How can I fix it?

```
Meine_Konfiguration [Android Application]   
DalvikVM [localhost:8615]   
    Thread [<1> main] (Suspended (exception RuntimeException))  
        <VM does not provide monitor information>   
        ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, Intent) line: 2211    
        ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, Intent) line: 2261 
        ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread, ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, Intent) line: 141    
        ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(Message) line: 1256  
        ActivityThread$H(Handler).dispatchMessage(Message) line: 99 
        Looper.loop() line: 137 
        ActivityThread.main(String[]) line: 5103    
        Method.invokeNative(Object, Object[], Class, Class[], Class, int, boolean) line: not available [native method]  
        Method.invoke(Object, Object...) line: 525  
        ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run() line: 737  
        ZygoteInit.main(String[]) line: 553 
        NativeStart.main(String[]) line: not available [native method]  
    Thread [<10> Binder_2] (Running)    
    Thread [<9> Binder_1] (Running)
```

These are my imports :

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.view.View;
import android.util.Log;
```

This is my MainActivity.class :

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private Button ButtonBar;
private Button ButtonRes;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ButtonBar = (Button) findViewById(R.id.barBTN);
    ButtonRes = (Button) findViewById(R.id.resBTN);

    ButtonBar.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent barIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, BarListActivity.class);
            startActivity(barIntent);      
            //finish();
        }
    });


    ButtonRes.setOnClickListener (new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent resIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, RestaurantListActivity.class);
            startActivity(resIntent);
            //finish();
        }
    });

}
```

Thanks for help

Comment: have you tried ` Intent barIntent = new Intent(this, BarListActivity.class);` ?

Comment: I got it. i changed <activity android:name=".BarListActivity"></activity>   to    <activity android:name="BarListActivity"></activity>